# How do I get the index from the beginning in a reversed iterator of chars of a string?

Tags: rust, iterator

This code:

```
let s = String::from("hi");

for (idx, ch) in s.chars().rev().enumerate() {
    println!("{} {}", idx, ch);
}
```

prints

```
0 i
1 h
```

but I want to know the real index, so that it would print:

```
1 i
0 h
```

What's the best way to do that? Currently I only think of first getting `.count()` and subtracting each `idx` from it, but maybe there's a better method that I overlooked.

Comment: Looks like there is no better method, since you can't get the last char number without calling `count` (explicitly of implicitly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is complicated, as they say. If your string is ASCII only, you can do the obvious enumeration then reverse against a `String`'s byte iterator:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hi");

    for (idx, ch) in s.bytes().enumerate().rev() {
        println!("{} {}", idx, ch as char);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work for Unicode strings in general because of what a [`char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/char/index.html) in Rust stands for:

> The `char` type represents a single character. More specifically, since 'character' isn't a well-defined concept in Unicode, char is a ['Unicode scalar value'](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value), which is similar to, but not the same as, a ['Unicode code point'](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#code_point).

This can be illustrated by the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("y̆");

    println!("{}", s.len());
    for (idx, ch) in s.bytes().enumerate() {
        println!("{} {}", idx, ch);
    }

    for (idx, ch) in s.chars().enumerate() {
        println!("{} {}", idx, ch);
    }
}
```

This weird looking string has length of 3, as in 3 `u8`s. At the same time it has 2 `char`s. So `ExactSizeIterator` can't be trivially implemented for `std::str::Chars`, but it can and does be implemented for `std::str::Bytes`. This is significant because to reverse a given iterator, it has to be `DoubleEndedIterator`:

```rust
fn rev(self) -> Rev<Self>
where
    Self: DoubleEndedIterator,
```

But `DoubleEndedIterator` is only available for enumeration iterator if the underlying iterator is also `ExactSizeIterator`:

```rust
impl<I> DoubleEndedIterator for Enumerate<I>
where
    I: ExactSizeIterator + DoubleEndedIterator,
```

In conclusion, you can only do `s.bytes().enumerate().rev()`, but not `s.chars().enumerate().rev()`. If you absolutely have to index the enumerated char iterator of a `String` that way, you are on your own.

Comment: Thank you. Yep, I've encountered an error that said `ExactSizeIterator` is not implemented or something when I tried `s.chars().enumerate().rev()`. Thanks for the explanation, it was entertaining and eyes-opening about the core reason!